# How to end a view and start a new activity?

Tags: android, view

I am developing an android game. I put all the game-related logic and UI in a view, and put the view in an activity. My problem is:

> How can i end the view by responding to key event and start a new
>   activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new Activity via the startActivity(Intent) method listed here.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)

To respond to a click event, in the xml file, put the android:onClick="functionName" as a property of the View that you want to be the 'button' (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick).

functionName(View v) should be defined in the Activity. The passed parameter will be a reference to the View that called the method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about managing views means remove a view on button click or any key event
you have use layout. you can add or remove views to/from layouts

### Remove View from layout

```
 layout.removeView(view);
        layout.removeViewInLayout(view);
        layout.removeViewAt(index);
        layout.removeAllViews();
```

### Add view to layout

```
layout.addView(child, index);
       layout.addView(child);
```

### start an activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityToBeOpen.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

or

```
                    Intent i = new Intent();

        i.setClassName("application packagename",
                "packagename.ActivityName");
        i.putStringArrayListExtra(CFMConstant.IMAGE_LIST_FOR_GRID_VIEW,
                fullImagePathList());
        startActivity(i);
```